# Filling combo box after choosing from another combox

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, combobox

I have two combo box, the first combo box is filled from database,then when i choose option from it `(onchange)`,it fills the second combo box,it works fine if the first combo box has more than one value but it doesn't work if the first combo box has only one option,can anyone help me why this happens?

```
<div>
    <label class="arrow-right"> Category Name</label><br>
    <select class="SelectStyle" style="width:95%;border:0;" name="CategoryName" id="CategoryName" onchange="GetOrderProduct(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)">
        <option value="">Select Category Name</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="arrow-right"> Category Type</label>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="SelectStyle" style="width:95%;border:0;" name="CategoryType" id="CategoryType" >
        <option value="">Select Category Type</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function GetOrderProduct(val)
{
    var sel=document.getElementById("OrderId");
    var OrdID = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_OrderProducts.php",
        data:{ 
           'CatName': val, 
           'OrderID':OrdID
        },
        success: function(data){

            $("#CategoryType").html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't happen, because with a single element in your dropdown, the change event never actually happens. If there's a single element, you may have to trigger the change event manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, with only one option in the drop down list, you can never change the selected item, so the `onchange` event never fires.  You could set up the element to have a `click` event as well as `change` event, but this would most likely become annoying and cause performance delays.

The bottom line is that with only one element, you'd have to trigger the code another way at another time.